# Is $\mathbb{Q}[[v^{-1}]] \cap \mathbb{Q}(v)=\mathbb{Q}[[v^{-1}]]$?

Tags: ring-theory, field-theory, representation-theory

I have a question about the some rings and fields. Is $\mathbb{Q}[[v^{-1}]] \cap \mathbb{Q}(v)=\mathbb{Q}[[v^{-1}]]$?

Comment: No. The power series that come from rational functions have several special properties and it's not hard to come up with one without those properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To amplify Qiaochu's comment: when you expand a rational function into a power series, you get an eventually periodic sequence of coefficients, basically for the very same reason the decimal expansion of a rational number is eventually periodic. Just use long division. Therefore, there are many series in $\mathbb{Q}[[v^{-1}]]$ that are not in $\mathbb{Q}(v)$.

EDIT: this was a bit too quick and a bit too simplistic. See David Speyer's comment below. (I was thinking about generating functions over finite fields).

Comment: +1: I hadn't been aware that the power series of a rational function is periodic, but the analogy with decimal expansion makes  it very clear. Good insight!

Comment: This is good analogy, but it isn't true as stated. For example, $1/(1-2v) = \sum 2^k v^k$, and $2^k$ is not periodic. The right statement is that the coefficient of $v^k$ in a rational generating series are of the form $\sum_{j=1}^N p_j(k) \alpha_j^k$, where the $p_j$ are polynomials and that $\alpha_j$ are complex numbers.

Comment: Right - thanks for the correction. Sorry.

Comment: The claim about periodicity almost works in the sense that for all but finitely many primes we can reduce any rational power series $\bmod p$ and the result must be (eventually?) periodic. On the other hand it is straightforward to find a power series which cannot be reduced modulo any prime.

Answer (score 2):

Or how about this: $\mathbb{Q}(v)$ is countable and $\mathbb{Q}[[v^{-1}]]$ isn't.

Or how about this: take $e^{v^{-1}} = \sum_{n \ge 0} \frac{v^{-n}}{n!}$. The derivatives of $p(v) e^{v^{-1}}$ never vanish identically (induction), so it can never be a polynomial. Hence $e^{v^{-1}}$ can't be a rational function.

Or, for a counterexample that works in any characteristic, take $f(v) = \sum_{n \ge 0} v^{-n^2}$. If $p(v)$ is a polynomial of degree $d$, then $p(v) f(v)$ has infinitely many nonzero coefficients because the gaps between nonzero terms in $f$ eventually become longer than $d$, so again $f(v)$ can't be a rational function.